# Always show file browser in TextMate 2

Tags: macos, editor, textmate

I've been working for a while with [TextMate 2](http://macromates.com/) and there's something I've never been able to solve.
Is it possible to always show the file browser at launch?
I know you can show it with ctrl+alt+cmd+D but I'd like it to always show at launch without having to make this shortcut (as I launch/quit TextMate many times in a day).
I'd be really grateful if anyone had a solution for this problem.
Thanks very much

Answer (score 3):

5 months ago, I contacted Michael Sheets from MacroMates Support and here's his answer:

> The file browser is shown when directories are opened or a favorite is open that is a directory. It is not shown when a single file is opened. If you want the file browser shown you should either open the directory itself or take advantage of the Favorite system.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested to. Did you already find out how to always show the file manager? Maybe it's possible through .tm_properties file?